# How to pass data to a programmatically created child view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

In my app, I have created a child view controller that I have instantiated with a storyboard ID. I then programmatically add this child view to a UIScrollView which is why I can't simply create a container view in the storyboard. Heres what I need to still do: I need to pass data to the child VC. I know how to pass data while using a segue to a VC, but how would I perform this operation in this case?

Comment: For this child view controller, have you created a new file that is a subclass of `UIViewController`?

Comment: How are you presenting it? Could you post the code you're using to add it to the scrollview?

Answer (score 1):

The controller that you're adding the child to has a childViewControllers property that contains any children that controller has. If you only have one child, then you can reference it from the parent with,

```
SomeClass *child = self.childViewControllers[0];
child.someProperty = self.propertyIWantToPass;
```

Comment: Instead of `[0]` I prefer `firstObject` or `lastObject` since they don't throw an exception if the array is empty, but I guess that's a matter of taste.

Comment: @HAS, yeah, I use those also for that reason in some circumstances. But here, the controller should have the child (so the array won't be empty). If it is empty, then the programmer has made a mistake, and the exception would alert him to that fact so he can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you want to send string data to ViewController2,ViewController3 from ViewController1.

Make property of the string variable in ViewController2 and ViewController3.

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *str;
```

And while pushing the ViewController2 and ViewController3:

```
  ViewController2 *viewController = [ViewController2 alloc]init];
  viewController2.str = @"Some text";
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
```

And you have the data send from ViewController1 in ViewController2.

Answer (score 0):

What about making a final destination for the data you want to pass in the child.

```
@interface ChildVC : UIViewController {
    @property (nonatomic) id myPrivateData;
}
- (id)initWithData:(id)data;
@end
```

Then passing in the data with the `-initWithData:` when you instantiate.

```
ParentVC *vc = [[ParentVC alloc] init];
vc.dataIWantToPass = ...;

ChildVC *child = [[ChildVC alloc] initWithData:vc.dataIWantToPass];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done iOS,

After looking at Apple's documentation I'm pretty sure you can't add a ViewController to UIScrollView. You need to give it something that inherits UIView. You could subclass your UIView and give it properties or a method to pass data into before giving it UIScrollView.

UIScrollView inherits from UIView so it has the property [UIScrollView.subviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW17) which can be used to access the VIew you passed into it, if the reference is no longer available.

---

If you're only manipulating a UIViewController or one of it's subclasses then you can access the subview it manages through its property [UIViewController.View](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW2)